# How to quickly find a pattern's effects in FL Studio

Tags: effects, fl-studio, interface

When I want to change the sound of a certain pattern, I first locate the pattern on the playlist. I then check in the channel rack, which is the playing channel in this pattern, I then locate the channel on the mixer, and only then do I find the active effects.

**Is there a quicker way to jump to the relevant effects from a pattern on the playlist view?**

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a shortcut to jump from a pattern on the playlist to its corresponding mixer channel. I assume this is because it is possible to combine multiple channel rack instruments within a single pattern.

I recommend keeping instrument, pattern and mixer insert names consistent so you can visually scan for them. Additionally, you could color code everything based on type (percussion, bass, leads, etc.)